# unable to display images on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

When i run the website locally, it works fine.However, after pushing to heroku, its displaying as a broken image

The pictures are in my /assets/images/ folder

images are called in my static page like this

```
<img src="assets/blank_avatar_male.jpg" alt="blank_male_avatar">
```

Ive tried changing the path to /assets/images/jpeg and it and repushed. No luck so far.
Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you make sure to add your new changes to `git` before pushing to heroku? That is, running `git add .`?

Comment: yep! did it with the original and used git push heroku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you don't have `config.serve_static_assets` set to true in your `production.rb` file.

The simplest solution is to include the `rails_12factor` gem which will do this for you

Comment: its weird, i actually have the rails_12factor gem? am i doing something wrong?

Comment: ok i changed the config.serve_static_assets to true and repushed to git and heroku. no luck so far :(

Comment: also, you should reference images via the rails image_tag helper, eg `<%= image_tag 'blank_avatar_male.png' %>`

Comment: thank you! the image tag fixed it! is it because heroku cant tell where to look for the images?

Comment: no - it's not heroku specific, you should always use `image_tag` - it ensures the paths are correct. Rails does magic with assets, notice that your asset will be in /assets/images but if you look at the output html for the img src it will be /assets.

Answer (score 0):

try compiling your assets locally like this:

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

and then push to heroku